# How to prevent useState variable to get reset every time my react components handles an event hook set with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I would like a react component to handle keyboard inputs. I have attached a simplified version of my component (that shows the problem I am having) below.

The problem is: The state variable `inputText` does not get updated. It appears that it gets set back to the initial value `""` every time I press a key. My assumption is that my component gets re-rendered every time I press a key. But why?

When using a "traditional" `input` element, this approach works perfectly fine. I have found many examples where the `value` of an `input` element is set to a state variable that is updated when the user types text into the `input` element (and the `onChange` event fires).

What I am doing wrong?

```
import './TestInput.css'
const { useState, useEffect } = require('react');

const TestInput = ( props ) => {
  const [ inputText, setInputText ] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
    console.log('Event listener added')
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
      console.log('Event listener removed');
    }
  }, []);

  function handleKeyPress(e) {
    setInputText(inputText + e.key);
  }

  return (
    <div id="container">
      <div id="input"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TestInput;
```

Comment: Any reason why you're attempting to use a div to act as an input instead of using an actual input?

Comment: Yes. I would like to create an input component that works like editors such as ACE or CodeMirror (which use - as far as I understand - a keyboard handler to manage their editor content which is made up of many divs and spans). I assume Visual Studio Code works in a similar way. The reason: I am not satisfied with the behaviour of contenteditable divs and I would like to control the input process for different purposes.

Comment: PS: And I am not using a traditional input element because I would like to use my component inside a data grid, etc. My assumption is that I can better control the layout if I just use divs that are "static". Many advanced data grids use divs (and not tables or standard input elements)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `useEffect` with empty array dependencies so  `window.addEventListener` only call once time with `handleKeyPress` in the first render. And in this function, you are using directly state `inputText` and it still has value is the initial value `''` and doesn't update to new state when event `keypress` was called.

The easiest way to fix is you don't use directly state `inputText` and pass the function to `setInputText`:

```
function handleKeyPress(e) {
  setInputText(preState => preState + e.key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I still don't fully understand. Why is `setInputText` accessible in my event handler whereas `inputText` is not (or at least the update of `inputText` is not reflected within my event handler)?